# Lazy loading in Cart page

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2

How to implement lazy loading in checkout cart page ?

Comment: Check this https://www.weltpixel.com/magento-2-lazy-loading-enhanced.html

Answer (score 0):

@KGR
In Weltpixel we dont have the feature for cart page. In that module, We have lazy load features like catalog page,search page and not cart page.

Answer (score 0):

I was used proto theme.

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ImageFactory" />
```

Block/Product/ImageFactory.php

```
<?php namespace Expedux\Checkout\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image as ImageBlock;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory as AssetImageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\ParamsBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\PlaceholderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;


/**
 * Create imageBlock from product and view.xml
 */
class ImageFactory extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $presentationConfig;

    /**
     * @var AssetImageFactory
     */
    private $viewAssetImageFactory;

    /**
     * @var ParamsBuilder
     */
    private $imageParamsBuilder;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var PlaceholderFactory
     */
    private $viewAssetPlaceholderFactory;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param ConfigInterface $presentationConfig
     * @param AssetImageFactory $viewAssetImageFactory
     * @param PlaceholderFactory $viewAssetPlaceholderFactory
     * @param ParamsBuilder $imageParamsBuilder
     * 
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        ConfigInterface $presentationConfig,
        AssetImageFactory $viewAssetImageFactory,
        PlaceholderFactory $viewAssetPlaceholderFactory,
        ParamsBuilder $imageParamsBuilder
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->presentationConfig = $presentationConfig;
        $this->viewAssetPlaceholderFactory = $viewAssetPlaceholderFactory;
        $this->viewAssetImageFactory = $viewAssetImageFactory;
        $this->imageParamsBuilder = $imageParamsBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve image custom attributes for HTML element
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return string
     */
    private function getStringCustomAttributes(array $attributes): string
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
            $result[] = $name . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
        return !empty($result) ? implode(' ', $result) : '';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve image class for HTML element
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return string
     */
    private function getClass(array $attributes): string
    {
        return $attributes['class'] ?? 'product-image-photo';
    }

    /**
     * Calculate image ratio
     *
     * @param int $width
     * @param int $height
     * @return float
     */
    private function getRatio(int $width, int $height): float
    {
        if ($width && $height) {
            return $height / $width;
        }
        return 1.0;
    }

    /**
     * Get image label
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $imageType
     * @return string
     */
    private function getLabel(Product $product, string $imageType): string
    {
        $label = $product->getData($imageType . '_' . 'label');
        if (empty($label)) {
            $label = $product->getName();
        }
        return (string) $label;
    }

    /**
     * Create image block from product
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $imageId
     * @param array|null $attributes
     * @return ImageBlock
     */
    public function create(Product $product, string $imageId, array $attributes = null): ImageBlock
    {
        $viewImageConfig = $this->presentationConfig->getViewConfig()->getMediaAttributes(
            'Magento_Catalog',
            ImageHelper::MEDIA_TYPE_CONFIG_NODE,
            $imageId
        );

        $imageMiscParams = $this->imageParamsBuilder->build($viewImageConfig);
        $originalFilePath = $product->getData($imageMiscParams['image_type']);

        if ($originalFilePath === null || $originalFilePath === 'no_selection') {
            $imageAsset = $this->viewAssetPlaceholderFactory->create(
                [
                    'type' => $imageMiscParams['image_type']
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $imageAsset = $this->viewAssetImageFactory->create(
                [
                    'miscParams' => $imageMiscParams,
                    'filePath' => $originalFilePath,
                ]
            );
        }

        $ratioWidth = $imageMiscParams['image_width'] ? intval($imageMiscParams['image_width']) : 0;
        $ratioHeight = $imageMiscParams['image_height'] ? intval($imageMiscParams['image_height']) : 0;

        $data = [
            'data' => [
                'template' => 'Vendor_Module::product/image_with_borders.phtml',
                'image_url' => $imageAsset->getUrl(),
                'width' => $imageMiscParams['image_width'],
                'height' => $imageMiscParams['image_height'],
                'label' => $this->getLabel($product, $imageMiscParams['image_type']),
                'ratio' => $this->getRatio($ratioWidth, $ratioHeight),
                'custom_attributes' => $this->getStringCustomAttributes($attributes),
                'class' => $this->getClass($attributes),
                'product_id' => $product->getId()
            ],
        ];

        return $this->objectManager->create(ImageBlock::class, $data);
    }
}
```

view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */ ?>

<span class="product-image-container"
      style="width:<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>px;">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper"
          style="padding-bottom: <?= ($block->getRatio() * 100) ?>%;">
        <img class="porto-lazyload <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getClass()) ?>"
            <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomAttributes()) ?>
            data-src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
            max-width="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
            max-height="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            alt="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getLabel(), null, true) ?>"/></span>
</span>
```